# How can I access the functions in the return value of this closure

Tags: javascript, function, closures

I am trying to call any of the functions in the return value of this closure but I am unable to:

```
function count() {
  var x = 0;
  return {
    increment: function() { ++x; },
    decrement: function() { --x; },
    get: function() { return x; },
    reset: function() { x = 0; }
  }
}
```

How can I call say "increment()" so it returns the incremented value of "x"?
I have tried:

- `var l = count();`, then `l.increment();` and it returns `undefined`!

Comment: Please show how you're trying to call the functions.

Comment: I have updated the question. @hereticmonkey

Comment: To return a value from a function, use the `return` keyword...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function works, but it returns nothing. You must use `get()` to get the current value:

```js
function count() {
  var x = 0;
  return {
    increment: function() { ++x; },
    decrement: function() { --x; },
    get: function() { return x; },
    reset: function() { x = 0; }
  }
}

let test= count();
console.log(test.get());
test.increment();
console.log(test.get());
test.increment();
console.log(test.get());
test.decrement();
console.log(test.get());
test.reset();

console.log(test.get());
```

But you could return the new value in every function:

```js
function count() {
  var x = 0;
  return {
    increment: function() { return ++x; },
    decrement: function() { return --x; },
    get: function() { return x; },
    reset: function() { return x = 0; }
  }
}

let test= count();
console.log(test.get());
console.log(test.increment());
console.log(test.increment());
console.log(test.increment());

console.log(test.decrement());

console.log(test.reset());
```

Comment: Ok, I see didn't know that the other functions were actually working and I had to get the value with the get function.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen if you want to get the values from the other functions, you can just do `return x` after the `x++` line, for example.

Comment: you can also do `return ++x;`, but note that you would get a different result if you did `return x++;`

Comment: Yes I know but didn't realize this at the onset, thank you!